# git: hash autocomplete

Tags: git, bash, ubuntu, autocomplete

Is there any chance to configure `git` to autocomplete the hashes when pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd>?

### Edit:

Please note that this question is not about *autocomplete*, but about **hash autocomplete**.
See my comment to VonC's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to consider *all* hashes from your repo, this is not likely because it wouldn't scale well (if you have several hundreds of commits, tags, ... each with their own hashes, this would quickly take a long time to list them all unless you have some caching system for this hash list)

If you limit the hashes to a fairly recent list (on the current branch for instance), may be, but that won't cover all use cases.

You have [here an example of git shell with different kind if tab expansion](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2010/03/07/using-git-with-windows-powershell/) (in PowerShell), [further enhanced here](http://markembling.info/view/git-powershell-revisited).
Even if your environment has no use for PowerShell, that gives you an idea of "tab expansion" implementation.

Comment: Thanks VonC. I'm asking this question because I was playing with `complete`, but all the commands are pretty expensive. I was hoping for some smart storing of last displayed hashes, e.g. via `git log` or `reflog`. The procedure is always the same: look for hash, then run a command on it. Actually I think it could be done with some bash scripting, although not easily.

Comment: @takeshin: I agree. I am curious to see if others will come with said "some smart storing of last displayed hashes". So far, they only read your question up to "auto completion", disregarding the "hash" aspect of it completely ;)

Comment: Well, reading with understanding should be programmers attribute ;)

Comment: If we just consider hashes of commits, I don't think we will get performance problem, since there are thousand of commands in a standard desktop linux system... (we probably don't have more than 5000 commits)

Answer (score 14):

You can refer to a commit by only its first few characters: git will autocomplete internally:

```
git checkout 9771
```

Thus, you actually don't have to enter the full hash!

Comment: This is nice, but I don't know whether 3,4,5 or 17 characters are enough.

Comment: You just need the minimum number of characters that make your hash unambiguous (given your list of revision hashes).  Thus, with a single commit, only 1 character is necessary, etc.  After 16 commits, you will need at least 2 characters, after 16*16 = 256 commits, 3 characters, etc.  Thus, for projects with about 1000 commits, I would guess that 4 characters should be enough most of the time.

Comment: PS: If git finds the first digits ambiguous, it will tell you, so there is no risk in not knowing immediately how many digits are needed.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I'm no bash expert. But I just tried to compile something like it for the csh family and this should be easy to transform into a bash completion script for those who know bash.

The command line I'm using to get useful, recent commit hashes is similar to:

```
(git branch | cut -c3-) ; (git branch | cut -c3- | xargs -ibranch git log -n 100 --pretty=format:%+H branch | sort -u)
```

This line works for both: bash and csh.

Basically it is the concatenation of the branch names:

```
git branch | cut -c3-
```

and the last  (with n being 100) commit names (=full hash numbers)

```
git branch | cut -c3- | xargs -ibranch git log -n 100 --pretty=format:%+H branch | sort -u
```

The full autocompletion statement for csh is then like this

```
#
# tcsh completion for Git
#
# Taken from: https://gist.github.com/1663989
# and from: https://gtirtha.wordpress.com/2010/05/14/git-autocomplete/
# extended and merged them into what I (Ingo Schmiegel) like

set _git_commands = (add am cherry-pick commit branch format-patch ls-files help remote merge pull push amend grep rebase reset revert bisect diff difftool blame log checkout fetch stash status wdiff config)
set _git_aliase = `git config --get-regexp 'alias.*' | sed -e 's,alias.,,' | cut -d' ' -f1`

complete git "p/1/($_git_commands $_git_aliase)/" \
  "n/help/($_git_commands $_git_aliase)/" \
  'n/add/`git status --porcelain|cut -c4-|xargs echo`/' \
  'n/br/`git branch|cut -c 3-`/' 'N/br/`git branch|cut -c 3-`/' \
  'n/branch/`git branch|cut -c 3-`/' 'N/branch/`git branch|cut -c 3-`/' \
  'n/cb/`git branch|cut -c 3-`/' \
  'n/cherry-pick/`(git branch|cut -c3-);(git branch|cut -c3-|xargs -ibranch git log -n 100 --pretty=format:%+h branch|sort -u)`/' \
  'n/co$/`git branch|cut -c 3-`/' \
  'n/config/(--global --get-regexp --list)/' \
  'n/diff/(--color-words --name-only)/' \
  'n/difftool/(--no-prompt --prompt --tool)/' \
  'n/fetch/`git remote`/' \
  'n/format-patch/`(echo --output-directory --stdout --signoff);(git branch|cut -c3-);(git branch|cut -c3-|xargs -ibranch git log -n 100 --pretty=format:%+h branch|sort -u)`/' \
  'n/log/`git branch|cut -c 3-|xargs echo -- --name-only --name-status --reverse --committer= --no-color --relative --ignore-space-change --ignore-space-at-eol --format=medium --format=full --format=fuller --color --decorate --oneline --summary`/' \
  'n/lg/`git branch|cut -c 3-|xargs echo -- --name-only --name-status --reverse --committer= --no-color --relative --ignore-space-change --ignore-space-at-eol --format=medium --format=full --format=fuller --color --decorate --oneline --summary`/' \
  'n/ls-files/(--cached --deleted --others --ignored --stage --unmerged --killed --modified --error-unmatch --exclude= --exclude-from= --exclude-standard --exclude-per-directory= --full-name --abbrev)/' \
  'n/merge/`git branch|cut -c 3-|xargs echo --no-commit --no-ff --ff-only --squash`/' \
  'N/merge/`git branch|cut -c 3-`/' \
  'n/pull/(--rebase --no-ff --squash)/' \
  'n/push/`git remote`/' 'N/push/`git branch|cut -c 3-`/' \
  'n/rebase/`git branch|cut -c 3-| xargs echo --continue --abort --onto --skip --interactive`/' \
  'N/rebase/`git branch|cut -c 3-`/' \
  'n/remote/(show add rm prune update)/' 'N/remote/`git remote`/' \
  'n/reset/(HEAD^)/' \
  'N/reset/(HEAD^)/' \
  'n/revert/`(echo --edit --no-edit --no-commit --mainline);(git branch|cut -c3-);(git branch|cut -c3-|xargs -ibranch git log -n 100 --pretty=format:%+h branch|sort -u)`/' \
  'n/stash/(apply list save pop clear show drop create branch)/' \
```

Note that this does not automatically detect the start of a hash and then can autocomplete it. csh autocompletion is based on the context of the previous word(s). In this example I'm using the hash completion only for the git commands `cherry-pick`, `format-patch`, and `revert` commands.

Answer (score -3):

Under Linux you have git shell: dev-vcs/git-sh, dev-util/easygit. Moreover if you enable bash completion for git you will get autocomplete.