# git checkout previous commit without mouse

Tags: git, version-control

Right now I always do a `git log` and copy/paste a hash to `git checkout <hash>` in order to checkout a previous commit and branch off from there, etc.

It would be really awesome if I could auto-complete commit hashes so I didn't have to type the whole thing, or rely on copy/paste with the mouse.

Is there a pro-tip that I'm missing?

Comment: If you tag your branches at critical points, auto-complete will work on those later

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759686/git-hash-autocomplete

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- If it's near a branch or tag use `^` or `~` notation e.g. `origin/master^^^`, `origin/master~3` (three commits before where `origin/master` is)

  - [Ancestry References](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Ancestry-References) — [Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book)
  - BTW - don't confuse XYZ~2 (2 commits back from with XYZ) and XYZ^2 (2nd parent of multiparent/merge commit XYZ)
- Use the "Short-SHA" - unique prefix of the hash (must be at least 4 chars and unique - I habitually tend to use 6 chars):

  - [Git Tools - Revision Selection](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Short-SHA-1) — [Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book)
  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3761086/11296 (read the comments too)

Answer (score 1):

Using `git log --oneline` is helpful, since you get just the abbreviated commit hash along with the first line of the commit message.  You could in theory pipe this through awk to grab the commit you want:

```
git checkout -b $(git log --oneline | awk '/something/ {print $1}')
```

...but that's a lot of typing, so not much of a time saver.  All the suggestions for relative commit references (`HEAD^`, `master~3`) and so forth are nice, but only really helpful (I think) for relatively recent commits.  I don't really like counting.

You could drop something like this into your shell dotfiles, assuming you're using bash:

```
function gen_git_revs()
{
        # Generate a list of named references.
        git show-ref | awk '{print $2}' | sed '
                /refs\/remotes/ {
                        s|refs/remotes/||
                        p
                        s|[^/]*/||
                }
                s|refs/tags/||
                s|refs/heads/||
                '

        # Generate a list of commits on the current
        # branch.
        git rev-list HEAD
}

function git_complete()
{
        local word=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
        COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "$(gen_git_revs)" $word))
}

complete -F git_complete git
```

This will let you tab-complete branch names (local and remote), tag names, and any commit ids accessible on your current branch (but in repositories with a very long history this could result in quite a pause as it generates the list of commit ids).  This is an off-the-cuff hack meant more as a demonstration of how to go about this than an actual solution.

But I will be honest with you:

I just copy and paste.

Answer (score 1):

You only need enough characters to make it unique; Git will complete the rest for you. If you don't use enough characters, Git will complain.

```
$ git log be
fatal: ambiguous argument 'be': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
$ git log be76
commit be7698e7582b7c995264e55767e86cb255c56833
Author: ...
Date:   Fri Feb 7 11:07:13 2014 -0800
```

Provide more if needed.

Answer (score -1):

Use notation such as `master~1` to refer to previous commit of that branch.